# Bootstrap form not passing value to php

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot understand why the input field "name" is not being passed to PHP. I tried commenting out the "name" code, but the same problem occurred with "company". I am setting the id and name properties on both input tags.

**Revised**

[website example](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/createAccount)

**HTML**

```
<form name="createAccount" role="form" method="POST" action="php/AddNewAccount.php" >
    <div data-toggle="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="user-type" id="writer" value="writer" class="sr-only" required >Writer
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="user-type" id="enabler" value="enabler" class="sr-only" required>Enabler
            </label>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" required id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Company:</label>
        <input class="form-control" required id="company" name="company">
    </div>
...
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function AddNewAccount() {
try {
    $acctType = $_POST["user-type"];
    if (!isset($acctType) || empty(trim($acctType))) {
        throw new Exception('You must select an account type."');       
    };
    echo "account-type=" . $acctType;
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    if (!isset($name) || empty(trim($name))) {
        throw new Exception('You must enter your name."');       
    };
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    if (!isset($company) || empty(trim($company))) {
        throw new Exception('You must enter your company name."');       
    };

...
}
```

**Error**

> [03-May-2016 21:41:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'You must enter your company name."' in
>   /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/AddNewAccount.php:18

Note the "user-type" is being passed correctly.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `trim` calls?

Comment: This code works for me as is, only changing `form action`, and `try` to `if(!empty($_POST))`, so there must be something else going on that we're not seeing in this simplified example

Comment: Likewise, I can't replicate this issue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ2TT.png Everything seems to function as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and efforts. I added a link to the website if that would help - at least with the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see; your Code should work... I couldn't spot any errors, though. But, Why do you have an extra  **(")** within your Exception Message? Are you using any Javascript on the Page? If Yes; I'd suggest you disable Javascript Temporarily and try sending the Form again without JS.

Could you try this instead?

```
function AddNewAccount() {
    // IT MIGHT BE A GOOD IDEA (IF YOU WILL) TO DUMP THE ENTIRE $_POST GLOBAL VARIABLE
    // AND END THE SCRIPT...(TEMPORARILY)... JUST TO SEE WHAT COMES BACK
    // var_dump($_POST); exit; // BYPASSTHE DUMPING SINCE WE ARE SURE COMPANY MAKES IT THROUGH TO THIS POINT...
    try {
        $name      = isset($_POST["name"])      ?  htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["name"]))       : null;
        $company   = isset($_POST["company"])   ?  htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["company"]))    : null;
        $acctType  = isset($_POST["user-type"]) ?  htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["user-type"]))  : null;

        if (!$acctType) {
            throw new Exception('You must select an account type.');       
        }

        if (!$name) {
            throw new Exception('You must enter your name.');       
        }

        if (!$company) {
            throw new Exception('You must enter your company name.');       
        }

...
}
```

This the Result from the var_dump($_POST) on your App.

[image]

As you can see, Your code is still consistent and you now have the Company in the list of your Data.... so you may want to **comment out the var_dump(); exit; part**

```
<?php
    //....PREVIOUS CODE
    // var_dump($_POST); exit; //NOW COMMENTED OUT TO CONTINUE WITH THE PROGRAM
```

Try this and let's know how it goes...
I sincerely hope it goes well with you Now, though ;-)

Comment: The dump returned "array(1) { ["user-type"]=> string(7) "enabler" }". Interesting. See the revison - I included a link to the web-page.

Comment: The Dump returns also the company as i tested your app... see my updated post for Visual...

Comment: I am totally puzzled. I made the changes you suggested, but I am still only dumping the first field - "user-type" when I try it. + 1 for effort.

Comment: @ron tornambe   Did you **COMMENT-OUT THE DUMP**? Anyways, I have uncommented it now in the Code... So try re-running the Code now without a Dump to see what you get....

Comment: The problem was an unlikely one. See my answer below. Your suggestion about the dump was vital in solving this issue. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 <form name="createAccount" role="form" method="POST" action="php/AddNewAccount.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

You can also parse it as a JSON:

```
 $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the form changes had no effect. This should be simple. See the revision that offers a link to the web-page.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the problem was with the input tags ending in ">" instead of "/>". I have been testing in Chrome. I tested in IE now and it works there too. Thanks for everyone's input.